# Insert only new entries in a sql table in python with hdbcli dbapi

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, hana, hdbcli

I have a SQL table (based on SAP HANA) with the following code:

```
from hdbcli import dbapi
conn = dbapi.connect(
        address  = os.getenv('DSP_ADDRESS'),
        port     = os.getenv('DSP_PORT'),
        user     = os.getenv('DSP_USER'),
        password = os.getenv('DSP_PASSWORD'))
cursor = conn.cursor()
output_data = list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO "DATABASE#PYTHON"."OUTLIER" VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
cursor.executemany(sql_insert, output_data)
conn.commit()
```

The dataframe `df` will add some new rows every months. How can I only insert the new rows, which are not existing in the current sql table? And second question, how can I exclude some columns from the checkup?
So for example:

```
SQL
Index  Value  Calendar
1       10      1
2       20      2
3       10      3
```

And I have the dataframe

```
df
Index  Value  Calendar
1       10      1
2       20      2
4       10      3
5       40      4
```

So I want only to insert the new row:

```
Index  Value  Calendar
5       40      4
```

into the existing sql table?

Comment: This is called "delta-loading" in dataware house environments - only load the data that has changed/been added since the last data load. If you can identify the new records in your data source (e.g. via a "last_updated" timestamp or something like that) then filtering the data before the INSERT is the way to go. 
Alternatively, you could insert the new dataframe into a temporary table in the database and then use the `MERGE INTO` command to have only the changed data put into the target table.